# Как получить ссылку на элемент из списка

Tags: java, android, listview

Написал свой адаптер для `ListView` в котором есть `checkbox`, `textview`, `progressbar`. Есть класс, который реализует загрузку файла по сети.

Мне необходимо отправить последовательно каждую выбранную ссылку из `ListView` на загрузку, вместе с ссылкой на `progressbar`, для отображения загрузки. Но вот незадача. Я не знаю как мне получить `progressbar` по позиции в `ListView`.

[Вот](http://pastebin.ru/3HH5hrLv) исходный код моего адаптера.

[Вот](http://pastebin.ru/XVPO6O37) исходный код класса контейнера, которым он заполнен.

Помогите мне пожалуйста реализовать метод адаптера:

> ProgressBar getProgressBar(int position) {
>       //??????? }

Кода может быть и много, но помогите пожалуйста. Не хочется костылями делать. Уже красоту навел с отображением прогресса загрузки и мультипоточностью.

Comment: Добавляйте исходный код в тело вопроса, а не на отдельные ресурсы.

Comment: Не для каждого элемента списка существует прогрессбар. Если у вас 100 элементов, но одновременно видно только 4, то всего прогрессбаров существует не больше 6 штук.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю вам проще, сделать один класс-модель
В классе вы опишите, тип(лучше сделать enum), и Object тоесть сам обьект
Реализуете `ArrayList<КЛАСС МОДЕЛЬ>`
Добавляете в list эти модели, и там где вам требуется обработать что-то, сравниваете тип из класс модели и вы точно знаете что это будет за Object из класс модели.
Или используйте `instanceof` но он как известно самый медленный в джаве. Это вам как идея.

Если понадобится напишу код. Или я не совсем понел о чем вы.

Ок, начнем, буду брать такие простые примеры

Начнем с небольшого примера

Создаем наши перечисления, в них вы будете описывать ваши типы.

```
package javaapplication21;

public enum myType {
    checkBox, miscBox
}
```

Создаем модель, которая будет использоватся в `ArrayList` или там где вам надо.

```
public class myModel {
    myType type = null;
    Object value = null;
    public myModel(myType type, Object value){
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        if(type==null)return null;
        return type.toString();
    }
}
```

Можно потом добавить все стандартные функции типо `eguals(сравнение двух моделей)`.

Теперь идем туда где будем это использовать.

```
package javaapplication21;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JavaApplication21 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<myModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new myModel(myType.checkBox, "Здесь ваш checkBox"));
        models.add(new myModel(myType.miscBox, "Здесь ваш miscBox"));
        //используем этот набор arraylist там где вам надо, пересылаете его и обрабатываете

        int a = 0;
        int max = models.size();
        while(a!=max){
            myModel model = models.get(a);
            if(model.type == myType.checkBox){
                System.out.println("Я знаю что это checkBox");
            }
            if(model.type == myType.miscBox){
                System.out.println("Я знаю что это miscBox");
            }

            a = a + 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Все очень просто, я везде такой метод использую.

Comment: Я думаю, что вы правильно поняли, но зато я не совсем понял, как это написать :)

Comment: если вам нужно прослушать что вы нажимаете в ListVIew вот отличная инструкция http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/listview.php как добавить слушатель, если это конечноже андроид

Answer (score -3):

Я с андроидом не игрался, но судя по этому [гайду](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html), все достаточно просто.

При инициализации `ProgressBar` вызываем следующий метод `progressBar.setMax(objects.size())`. Здесь мы указываем количество ячеек, которое будет обработано. А дальше, в ходе выполнения, вызываем `progressBar.setProgress(ЗЮ)`, где указываем число уже обработанных ячеек.